# aws eks nlb - hetrogenous ingress and single ingress-nginxcontroller

Tags: amazon-eks, nlb, ingress-controller

One of our cluster setup has two ingress. one ingress is configured to use https backend and another is configured to use http. what should be the value configured on ingress-nginx-controller service `service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol:`  annotation